localhost 3000 shows a blank page in nextjs app.(14.2)
I'm encountering an issue with my Next.js application where it intermittently shows a blank page in Chrome. Here are the details of the problem:
Problem Description:
The page loads as expected initially, but after some time, it turns into blank page.clearing the browser cache temporarily resolves the issue, but it reappears eventually.
Steps Taken:
Cleared the browser cache.
Tried loading the page in Incognito mode.(it works for a while)
Verified that the issue persists across different Chrome versions.
Checked for errors in the Chrome Developer Console, but nothing unusual was reported.
Environment:
Next.js Version: 14.2
Chrome Version: lastest version i reinstalled
Operating System: win10
What I’ve Tried:
Restarted the development server.
This is how my app renders.
Question:
Has anyone experienced similar issues with Next.js showing a blank page intermittently in Chrome? If so, how did you resolve it? Any insights or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated.
Has anyone experienced similar issues with Next.js showing a blank page intermittently in Chrome? If so, how did you resolve it? Any insights or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated.

i uninstalled the chrom but it still works at first time when i open the app on localhost. and when i refreshed the page it showed blank page

Can you provide any logs from your console running the app server? It looks like something is crashing you app and it doesn't seem to be related to the browser but a rendering issue.

no errors. no logs but it works now i delete some new code , it works now
